# UINavigationController and UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have set up my UINavigationController and I'm wondering how I can integrate a UIWebView with a standard back button. When a linked is taped, I want to push it to the next view.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [the UIWebViewDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). You'll probably want to implement this in your view controller and then set your view controller as the web view's delegate. When a link is clicked the web view will invoke the

```
webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```

method. In that, you can see what URL the user is trying to go to. If you don't want the web view to navigate there but to push another view controller onto the nav controller stack, you just do the pushViewController there and then return NO.

I'm not sure what you want to do with the back button - can you clarify?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just mean a standard back button after pushing a new view.

Comment: Well, the standard left nav button you'll get from the nav controller will take you back to the previous view in the stack, which will probably give you the effect you want if you've done what I've suggested above to push a new view controller each time a link is clicked.  If you want the web view to navigate backwards, you can call the goBack method on UIWebView. You can hook up a button and do this in its delegate. There is also a canGoBack property which tells you if the web view can go back or not. You can use this to enable/disable the button if needed.

Comment: If my response has answered your question, would you mind marking this as answered?